# C pointers in a 2-D array context

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Here is working program that has an 8 by 8 array representing a mini chessboard. The actual chessboard is 4 by 4 and filled with zeros in the array.

```
// Chessboard representation
//
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char uuboard[8][8]={
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1}, {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},   
{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1}, {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},   
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} };     

unsigned char *uboard[8]={uuboard[0]+2, uuboard[1]+2, uuboard[2]+2, uuboard[3]+2,
                          uuboard[4]+2, uuboard[5]+2, uuboard[6]+2, uuboard[7]+2};
unsigned char **board=uboard+2;

int main(void) {
    // Make a change to the board directly, using 2-D array
    uuboard[3][3] = 8;
    printf("Print the board by accessing the 2-D array directly\n");
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
            printf("%d", uuboard[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Print again using pointers\n");
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++, printf("\n")) {
      for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
          printf("%d", board[i][j]);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");   
    return 0;
}
```

The original programmer appears to use pointers so he/she gets to the actual chessboard squares by starting the index at 0, not 2. This is puzzling. How does `*uboard[8]` and `**board` do the job? Most grateful for any answers or references to answers.

Comment: I suggest you draw it all out on paper, first the `uuboard` arrays (but not as a matrix but as sequential and contiguous values), then `uboard` and draw arrows to where the pointers are pointing, and lastly `board` with an arrow where it is pointing. And remember that e.g. `uuboard[2]+2` is equal to `&uuboard[2][2]`, and `uboard+2` is equal to `&uboard[2]`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Long-hand drawing is always helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
unsigned char *uboard[8]={uuboard[0]+2, uuboard[1]+2, uuboard[2]+2, uuboard[3]+2, uuboard[4]+2, uuboard[5]+2, uuboard[6]+2, uuboard[7]+2};
```

is equivalent to

```
unsigned char *uboard[8]={&uuboard[0][2], &uuboard[1][2], &uuboard[2][2], &uuboard[3][2], &uuboard[4][2], &uuboard[5][2], &uuboard[6][2], &uuboard[7][2]};
```

and

```
unsigned char **board=uboard+2;
```

is equivalent to

```
unsigned char **board = &uboard[0]+2; 
// or 
unsigned char **board = &uboard[2];
```

Comment: uuboard[0]+2 was too cryptic for me, &uuboard[0][2] is better. Putting in the ampersand and the two indices helped me a lot. Many thanks

Comment: @Fishsticks; I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here unsigned char *uboard[8] is array of pointer which can store 8 pointers to unsigned characters.
Now uboard[0] = uuboard[0]+2.

- uuboard[0] is a pointer to array of 8 characters --> {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} i.e. first array in uuboard[8][8].
- uboard[0] + 2 means --> uboard[0] + memory of next 2 arrays of 8 characters (As the type of pointer is char (*)[8]--> pointer to array of 8 characters.)
  Hence uboard[0]+2 = uboard[2].